# How to run 2 processes at the same time in C?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm creating a program in C like terminal shell in which is my exercise in class. That program allow to run multiple processes at the same time if you add '&' at end of sentence. ( example : $ gedit & ); However, my code just run father process when child process exit.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

void  parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
     while (*line != '\0') {       /* if not the end of line ....... */ 
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
              *line++ = '\0';     /* replace white spaces with 0    */

          *argv++ = line;          /* save the argument position     */
          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && 
                 *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') 
               line++;             /* skip the argument until ...    */
     }
     *argv = '\0';                 /* mark the end of argument list  */
}


void  execute(char **argv)
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
          printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
               printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     else {                                  /* for the parent:      */
            wait(NULL);                          /* wait for completion  */

     }
}

void  main(void)
{
     char  line[1024];             /* the input line                 */
     char  *argv[64];              /* the command line argument      */

     while (1) {                   /* repeat until done ....         */
          printf("COMMAND -> ");     /*   display a prompt             */
          gets(line);              /*   read in the command line     */
          printf("\n");
          parse(line, argv);       /*   parse the line               */
          if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)  /* is it an "exit"?     */
               exit(0);            /*   exit if it is                */
          execute(argv);           /* otherwise, execute the command */
     }
}
```

**I want to result like:**

Ex: $ gedit &   // program gedit run with pid = 4789

$ emacs // program emacs run with pid = 5123 ppid = 4789

Comment: Presumably, the parent process is waiting because it calls the `wait` function.

Comment: @Adrian : I know; but I don't know how to execute multiple processes.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to run multiple *child* processes? Then you will need to call `fork` multiple times. Of course, you can't call `fork` while the parent process is waiting, so you will need to find some way around that.

Comment: please answer this
https://stackoverflow.com/q/44795576/8206518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit the `wait()` if you see an ampersand:

```
void  execute(char **argv, int block)
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
          printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {
               printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     else if (block) {
            wait(NULL);
     }
}
```

Comment: And when you have multiple children, you'll want to use `waitpid` instead of `wait` so you wait for the correct one.

Comment: How do I know if the process completed without waiting? In my programming task I have a prompt that keeps asking the user for commands to execute (this process should never have to wait). However, it can only run 2 processes simultaneously otherwise it should get added to a queue. I therefore need a way to fork the next process after one of the 2 processes finished.

Comment: I asked my question on StackOverflow but haven't gotten an answer so far. I would appreciate your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887417/fork-multiple-process-simultaneously-without-blocking-main-thread