# Fork multiple process simultaneously without blocking main thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

This is more of a general question than a coding question and I would appreciate some directions or a general approach.

My programming task is to implement a simple job scheduler that will execute non-interactive jobs. At any given time only 4 jobs should be executing. If more than 4 jobs are submitted, then these additional jobs must wait until one of the 4 executing jobs are completed. A prompt will keep asking the user to enter a command that should be executed.

This means that the main thread, or to be precise the main function that runs the infinite loop asking the user to enter a command, should never be blocked or waiting on a process to finish. Using `fork()` and `exec()` and `wait()` will cause my main process to wait which is not the desired behavior. Therefore, I thought of omitting the `wait()` in the parent process and using a signal handler for SIGCHLD to catch the instant when the forked process terminated. I would have a global variable holding the value of how many process are running at any given time.

Is this the right approach or is there a better/more elegant solution to that?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: *"I would have a global variable holding the value of how many process are running at any given time..."* - Semaphore. It is a [counted signal](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Semaphores.html). Also of interest may be [`sigsuspend`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigsuspend.html) to avoid a `pause()` in a busy loop on the main thread while waiting for a signal.

Comment: Another possibility is to call forkpty() instead of fork(); that will return a file descriptor to you (via its first argument) which you can select() and read() on to read the child process's stdout and (more importantly) if the child process goes away, the read() will return 0 to notify you that the pipe is closed, and you can respond by calling wait() (which will return immediately) and taking whatever other steps are necessary (e.g. launching the next waiting process)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - interesting `forkpty()` is a BSD function I had not yet stumbled across. So passing `winp` as `NULL` suppresses the window?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, I really appreciate it! Though I am not sure if I am allowed to use forkpty() since we haven't covered it yet in lecture but I will definately look into it and see if that would help it. Would you say my implementation makes sense or is there anything that you would do differently? @JeremyFriesner

Comment: Thanks for the help! I should use Semaphores to solve the problem of interference, e.g. multiple processes accessing the global variable at the same time. Is that what you mean?I don't get the benefit of sigsuspend. What do you think of my implementation? Any other suggestions or does it seem alright? I appreciate your input! @jww

Comment: The approach looks good to me.

Comment: Appreciate it! @alk